# FFMPEG change videos size

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

How do i change a video that is 1920x1080 to 1080x1920, and then "shrink" it so that it fills only half of the 1080x1920 screen size?
here is what i mean:

[1920x1080 original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bgjd.png)

needs to be changed to

[1080x1920 that covers 50% of screen space only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX9TQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `scale` filter, then the `pad` filter. The following command first scales the video from `width x height` to `height x (width/2)`, then adds padding at the bottom, preserving the width and duplicating the height. The `setsar` filter changes the aspect ration for the output video. `iw` and `ih` stand for input width and height.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=ih:iw/2,setsar=1,pad=0:ih*2" output.mp4
```